# How to Reverse Rolling Sum?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rolling sum calculated on a grouped data frame but its adding up the wrong way, it is a sum of the future, when I need a sum of the past.

What am I doing wrong here?

I import the data and sort by Dimension and Date (I have tried removing the date sort already)

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', parse_dates=True)
df.sort_values(['Dimension','Date'])
print(df)
```

I then create a new column which is a multi index grouped by rolling window

```
new_column = df.groupby('Dimension').Value1.apply(lambda x: 
x.rolling(window=3).sum())
```

I then reset the index to be the same as the original

```
df['Sum_Value1'] = new_column.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print(df)
```

I have also tried reversing the index before the calculation, but that also failed.

Input

```
Dimension,Date,Value1,Value2
1,4/30/2002,10,20
1,1/31/2002,10,20
1,10/31/2001,10,20
1,7/31/2001,10,20
1,4/30/2001,10,20
1,1/31/2001,10,20
1,10/31/2000,10,20
2,4/30/2002,10,20
2,1/31/2002,10,20
2,10/31/2001,10,20
2,7/31/2001,10,20
2,4/30/2001,10,20
2,1/31/2001,10,20
2,10/31/2000,10,20
3,4/30/2002,10,20
3,1/31/2002,10,20
3,10/31/2001,10,20
3,7/31/2001,10,20
3,1/31/2001,10,20
3,10/31/2000,10,20
```

Output:

```
    Dimension        Date  Value1  Value2  Sum_Value1
0           1   4/30/2002      10      20         NaN
1           1   1/31/2002      10      20         NaN
2           1  10/31/2001      10      20        30.0
3           1   7/31/2001      10      20        30.0
4           1   4/30/2001      10      20        30.0
5           1   1/31/2001      10      20        30.0
6           1  10/31/2000      10      20        30.0
7           2   4/30/2002      10      20         NaN
8           2   1/31/2002      10      20         NaN
9           2  10/31/2001      10      20        30.0
10          2   7/31/2001      10      20        30.0
11          2   4/30/2001      10      20        30.0
12          2   1/31/2001      10      20        30.0
13          2  10/31/2000      10      20        30.0
```

Goal Output:

```
    Dimension        Date  Value1  Value2  Sum_Value1
0           1   4/30/2002      10      20        30.0
1           1   1/31/2002      10      20        30.0
2           1  10/31/2001      10      20        30.0
3           1   7/31/2001      10      20        30.0
4           1   4/30/2001      10      20        30.0
5           1   1/31/2001      10      20         NaN
6           1  10/31/2000      10      20         NaN
7           2   4/30/2002      10      20        30.0
8           2   1/31/2002      10      20        30.0
9           2  10/31/2001      10      20        30.0
10          2   7/31/2001      10      20        30.0
11          2   4/30/2001      10      20        30.0
12          2   1/31/2001      10      20         Nan
13          2  10/31/2000      10      20         NaN
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can shift the result by `window-1` to get the left aligned results:

```
df["sum_value1"] = (df.groupby('Dimension').Value1
                      .apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=3).sum().shift(-2)))
```

[image]

Comment: I think you're misled by constant values in OP's example, but the need is to do a reverse sum

Comment: @Boud I did overlook that part. But I think this still gives the correct result coincidently :). As really, the past or future here is just where you put the sum results if the data is sorted by Date. Or maybe OP just needs to sort the data frame by Date in ascending order initially.

Comment: Sneaky @Boud cheated and read the "words" in OP's post /shakes_head

Answer (score 11):

You need a backward sum, therefore reverse your series before sum rolling it:

```
lambda x: x[::-1].rolling(window=3).sum()
```

Answer (score 6):

Rolling backwards is the same as rolling forward and then shifting the result:

```
x.rolling(window=3).sum().shift(-2)
```

Comment: You need to use `apply` as in Psidom's answer, or it will shift across groups.

Comment: Shifting will result in NaN values at the end where there shouldn't be any. Reversing the entire series, rolling, and then reversing back solves this. e.g. `x[::-1].rolling(3).sum()[::-1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
import pandas as pd

from pandas.api.indexers import FixedForwardWindowIndexer

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxxx\python\data.txt')

indexer = FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=3)

df1 = df.join(df.groupby('Dimension')['Value1'].rolling(indexer, min_periods=3).sum().to_frame().reset_index(), rsuffix='_sum')

del df1['Dimension_sum']
del df1['level_1']

df1
```

Input:

```
    Dimension        Date  Value1  Value2
0           1   4/30/2002      10      20
1           1   1/31/2002      10      20
2           1  10/31/2001      10      20
3           1   7/31/2001      10      20
4           1   4/30/2001      10      20
5           1   1/31/2001      10      20
6           1  10/31/2000      10      20
7           2   4/30/2002      10      20
8           2   1/31/2002      10      20
9           2  10/31/2001      10      20
10          2   7/31/2001      10      20
11          2   4/30/2001      10      20
12          2   1/31/2001      10      20
13          2  10/31/2000      10      20
14          3   4/30/2002      10      20
15          3   1/31/2002      10      20
16          3  10/31/2001      10      20
17          3   7/31/2001      10      20
18          3   1/31/2001      10      20
19          3  10/31/2000      10      20
```

OUTPUT:

```
    Dimension        Date  Value1  Value2  Value1_sum
0           1   4/30/2002      10      20        30.0
1           1   1/31/2002      10      20        30.0
2           1  10/31/2001      10      20        30.0
3           1   7/31/2001      10      20        30.0
4           1   4/30/2001      10      20        30.0
5           1   1/31/2001      10      20         NaN
6           1  10/31/2000      10      20         NaN
7           2   4/30/2002      10      20        30.0
8           2   1/31/2002      10      20        30.0
9           2  10/31/2001      10      20        30.0
10          2   7/31/2001      10      20        30.0
11          2   4/30/2001      10      20        30.0
12          2   1/31/2001      10      20         NaN
13          2  10/31/2000      10      20         NaN
14          3   4/30/2002      10      20        30.0
15          3   1/31/2002      10      20        30.0
16          3  10/31/2001      10      20        30.0
17          3   7/31/2001      10      20        30.0
18          3   1/31/2001      10      20         NaN
19          3  10/31/2000      10      20         NaN
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the different options in from pandas.api.indexers?

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse_rolling(series, window, func):
    index = series.index
    series = pd.DataFrame(series.iloc[::-1])
    series = series.rolling(window, 1).apply(func)
    series = series.iloc[::-1]

    series['index'] = index
    series = series.set_index('index')
    return series[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had to do the same thing myself and came up with a simple one-liner:

`df['Sum_Value1'] = df['Value1'].iloc[::-1].rolling(window = 3).sum()`