# Pandas reverse rolling sum using offset with varying windows sizes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation

Consider the following dataframe:

```
    date                    values
0   2020-01-07 09:00:00     5
1   2020-01-07 10:00:00     8
2   2020-01-07 11:00:00     9
3   2020-01-07 12:00:00     5
4   2020-01-07 13:00:00     0
5   2020-01-07 14:00:00     0
6   2020-01-07 15:00:00     1
7   2020-01-07 16:00:00     7
8   2020-01-08 09:00:00     6
9   2020-01-08 10:00:00     9
10  2020-01-08 11:00:00     2
11  2020-01-08 12:00:00     4
12  2020-01-08 13:00:00     5
13  2020-01-08 14:00:00     2
14  2020-01-08 15:00:00     4


df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='1/7/2020', freq='BH', periods=20),
             'values':np.random.randint(0, 10, 20)})
```

I want to create a new column that contains the sum of the `values` column over the coming 11 hours. I used `df.rolling('11H', on='date').sum()`, however this calculates the `sum` over the previous 11 hours.

I came across solution like [How to Reverse Rolling Sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101652/how-to-reverse-rolling-sum), but as my date column only contains business-hours, I cannot simply shift the results (as I don't know how many rows I have to shift, due to the varying window sizes).

It works by doing `df.iloc[::-1].rolling('11H', on='date').sum().iloc[::-1]`, but it feels a bit hacky to reverse the `dataframe` twice. Are there any other elegant solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.api.indexers import FixedForwardWindowIndexer
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='1/7/2020', freq='BH', periods=20),
             'values':np.random.randint(0, 10, 20)})
indexer = FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size = 11)
df2 = df1.join(df1['values'].rolling(indexer, min_periods=1).sum(), rsuffix='11rollfwd')
```

Results-

```
Source:
                  date  values
0  2020-01-07 09:00:00       9
1  2020-01-07 10:00:00       7
2  2020-01-07 11:00:00       2
3  2020-01-07 12:00:00       4
4  2020-01-07 13:00:00       4
5  2020-01-07 14:00:00       7
6  2020-01-07 15:00:00       4
7  2020-01-07 16:00:00       8
8  2020-01-08 09:00:00       4
9  2020-01-08 10:00:00       0
10 2020-01-08 11:00:00       6
11 2020-01-08 12:00:00       8
12 2020-01-08 13:00:00       7
13 2020-01-08 14:00:00       0
14 2020-01-08 15:00:00       1
15 2020-01-08 16:00:00       1
16 2020-01-09 09:00:00       1
17 2020-01-09 10:00:00       6
18 2020-01-09 11:00:00       1
19 2020-01-09 12:00:00       2

Target
                  date  values  values11rollfwd
0  2020-01-07 09:00:00       9             55.0
1  2020-01-07 10:00:00       7             54.0
2  2020-01-07 11:00:00       2             54.0
3  2020-01-07 12:00:00       4             52.0
4  2020-01-07 13:00:00       4             49.0
5  2020-01-07 14:00:00       7             46.0
6  2020-01-07 15:00:00       4             40.0
7  2020-01-07 16:00:00       8             42.0
8  2020-01-08 09:00:00       4             35.0
9  2020-01-08 10:00:00       0             33.0
10 2020-01-08 11:00:00       6             33.0
11 2020-01-08 12:00:00       8             27.0
12 2020-01-08 13:00:00       7             19.0
13 2020-01-08 14:00:00       0             12.0
14 2020-01-08 15:00:00       1             12.0
15 2020-01-08 16:00:00       1             11.0
16 2020-01-09 09:00:00       1             10.0
17 2020-01-09 10:00:00       6              9.0
18 2020-01-09 11:00:00       1              3.0
19 2020-01-09 12:00:00       2              2.0
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution that takes the sum over the following 11 hours. As there's only business hours in the `date` columns a fixed window of size 11 will not do the trick unfortunately (window size will vary depending on the windows' starting row).