# How to calculate backwards moving average in python for 1D time series?

Tags: python, pandas, signal-processing

I have a 1D time series dataframe (q5 second sampling) and median mean arterial pressure (MAP) in my other column (see below for example of the dataframe).

[dataframe head and tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL6Qp.png)

I've calculated a 10 minute moving average using pd.rolling(window_size).mean().

```
#10 minute moving average 
window_size = 120

df_1_windows = df_1.MAP_MEDIAN.rolling(window_size)


df_1['ma'] = df_1_windows.mean().tolist()
df_1.plot(ylim=0)
```

[image: graph of 10 minute moving average vs median MAP]

[head and tail of dataframe with moving average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUxt6.png)

**Issue**: After looking at the above figure, my boss said he wanted me to look into a *'backwards moving mean'* because what I created (above) is a non-causal filter, and therefore requires 'future' values (i.e., i+1, i+2, etc...) to calculate. The backwards moving mean being causal, as opposed to non causal. [This is a site that references backwards moving average for data denoising](https://dataprocessing.aixcape.org/DataPreprocessing/DataCleaning/DataDenoising/DataDenoisingWithBackwardMovingAverage/index.html)

After spending a lot of time on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101652/how-to-reverse-rolling-sum) here is my solution: [I inverted the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS8Uy.png) and then used the same code from above to calculate a rolling 10 minute mean.

```
#10 minute moving average in reverse?
window_size = 120

df_1_reverse_windows = df_1_reverse.MAP_MEDIAN.rolling(window_size)


df_1_reverse['ma'] = df_1_reverse_windows.mean().shift(-2).tolist()
df_1_reverse.plot(ylim=0)
```

[plot of backwards 10 minute moving average vs median MAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weg4C.png)
(note the shift)

**Question:** How do I know if I did this correctly? I'm feeling pretty lost!

Comment: cant you use `df_2_windows = df_1.MAP_MEDIAN[::-1].rolling(window_size)[::-1]` (maybe you will need a iloc after MEDIAN not sure, i don't use pandas that much). But the idea is to reverse your data, calculate the rolling  and then reverse it again

Comment: please do not post images of data, provide **text**

Comment: never done this before so i apologize... will keep in mind for next time. thank you.

Comment: The window in `pandas.Series.rolling` is trailing by default, meaning the right edge of the window is aligned to the value you're creating the mean for. Unless your time series is decreasing in time as it progresses then you're now calculating a leading window and introducing the causal problems you're trying to avoid. This should be clear from your plot as the moving average "knows" about peaks before they occur.

Comment: You did it right the first time.  Did you show your boss exactly the same figure?  Maybe he was confused by the NaNs at the beginning.

Comment: @Riley so what you're saying is that I don't have to invert anything. In fact, my original solution was correct? Would you mind explaining further? thank you for your time!

Comment: @Iain Yes your original solution is correct - your boss is confused.  If you haven't heard of the term "target leakage" or "data leakage" then start there.  If you apply a window to calculate the mean and it is not a trailing window, then you will be incorporating information about future state and you will end up with target leakage.  A major clue that you had the right approach is this: if leading windows were required for calculating rolling means without introducing causal effects then they'd be common - and implemented in pandas, and you wouldn't have to jump through hoops to create it.

Comment: @Iain a trailing window for a rolling mean already calculates a "backwards moving mean".  When you google this term you will not find many results and I suspect is because it is so trivial you don't really need a name for it.  Have a look at the formula and convince yourself it is just calculating a rolling mean with a trailing window.

Comment: @Iain and again, look at your last graph.  At the start the orange mean is heading downwards before the blue line does - it knows what's coming before the blue line does, and this means it has been calculated with knowledge of future state.

Comment: @Riley hey man thank you so much for your time and effort, this makes a lot of sense. I really appreciate it.