# How to fill the final values of a pandas DataFrame when performing a backwards rolling calculation?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a backwards rolling sum in a pandas DataFrame `pd.DataFrame.rolling`. For this I use the answers from [How to Reverse Rolling Sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101652/how-to-reverse-rolling-sum). However, I cannot seem to fill the last values, i.e. these stay nan. I tried the build-in option `min_periods=0`, but this does not work. Does anybody have any idea how to do a backwards rolling sum, and leave no values as nan?

Say I have the following DataFrame with backwards rolling calculation. In my actual dataset I perform these calculations over multiple ID groups, but this does not matter for the problem at hand.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,0], [2, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1]], columns=['Id', 'Test'])
df['Outcome'] = df['Test'].rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).sum().shift(-(1))
```

Outcome:

```py
   Id  Test  Outcome
0   2     0      0.0
1   2     0      0.0
2   2     0      1.0
3   2     1      NaN
```

Expected outcome:

```
   Id  Test  Outcome
0   2     0      0.0
1   2     0      0.0
2   2     0      1.0
3   2     1      1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .fillna method:

```py
df.fillna(method="ffill")
```

which returns:

```
   Id  Test  Outcome
0   2     0      0.0
1   2     0      0.0
2   2     0      1.0
3   2     1      1.0
```